# Is this a correct way to use the Deferred object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm building a App that need to list the categories and subcategories of a Product.

When a user selects a category, the subcategories related to this category are loaded from the server with ajax, but only if they have not been loaded later (in this case they are loaded from the DOM).

Code: http://jsbin.com/abijad/edit#javascript,html

```
var $form = $('#new-product-form');

$form.on( 'change', 'select.product-categories', function( e ) { //I'm using event delegation for a future feature...

  getSubCategories( $(this).val() ).done( function( $subCategoriesEl ){
    $form.find( 'select.product-subcategories' ).not( $subCategoriesEl ).hide();
    $subCategoriesEl.show();
  });

});

var getSubCategories = function( categoryId ) {

    var dfd = $.Deferred(),
        $alreadyisLoaded = $form.find( 'select.product-subcategories' ).map( function( idx, el ){
      if( parseInt( $( this ).data( 'category' ), 10 ) === parseInt( categoryId, 10 ) ){
            return el;
          } 
        });

      if( $alreadyisLoaded.length > 0 ){ //don't request subCategories that already are loaded
        console.log( 'SubCategory loaded from DOM' );
        dfd.resolve( $alreadyisLoaded );
      } else {
        var subCategoriesHtml = '<select data-category="' + categoryId +  '" class="product-subcategories">';

        $.get( '/', { //The ajax request will only be simulated
          categoryId : categoryId
        }, function ( result ) {
          //simulate success :X
          result = {"status":1,"data":[{"name":"Sub-Category I","id":1},{"name":"Sub-Category II","id":2},{"name":"Sub-Category III","id":3}]};

          console.log( 'SubCategory loaded with Ajax' );

          if( result.status === 1 ) { //Success

            for( var subCategoryInfo in result.data) {
              if( result.data.hasOwnProperty( subCategoryInfo ) ){
                subCategoriesHtml += '<option value="' + result.data[subCategoryInfo].id + '">';
                subCategoriesHtml += result.data[subCategoryInfo].name + '</option>';
              }
            }

            subCategoriesHtml += '</select>';

            var $subCategories = $( subCategoriesHtml ).hide().appendTo( $form );

            dfd.resolve( $subCategories );
          } else {
            dfd.reject();
          }
        });
      }

      return dfd.promise();

};
```

---

```
<form id="new-product-form">
  <select class="product-categories">
    <option value="1">Category I</option>
    <option value="2">Category II</option>
    <option value="3">Category III</option>
    <option value="4">Category IV</option>
    <option value="5">Category V</option>
  </select>
  <select data-category="1" class="product-subcategories">
    <option value="1">SubCategory I</option>
    <option value="2">SubCategory II</option>
    <option value="3">SubCategory III</option>
    <option value="4">SubCategory IV</option>
    <option value="5">SubCategory V</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Because the code was getting full of callback here and there, I decided to use the jQuery Deferred object, but I do not know if this is the correct implementation. Could someone tell me I did the right thing, or should I do differently?

Comment: Please include the relevant code within the question in addition to the link.  The aim is to keep SO as self-sufficient as possible.  Questions should still be relevant if external sites disappear.

Comment: I would have just cached the deferred objects and re-built the options on each subsequent change to avoid eventually having a large number of hidden elements in a very large category/sub category situation, but other than that, what you have will work as long as the number of elements doesn't get too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything glaringly incorrect. All in all, you are using the deferred in the correct fashion: to abstract away the possibly dual-synchronistic nature of your method. Now, that being said, if this were code appearing in my codebase, this is how I would write it. The main points being: don't use `for in` on arrays, build strings with arrays, consistent naming and spacing, and just some other terse JS preferences. These are a matter of taste, so otherwise, good job:

```
(function() {
    var getSubCategories = function ( categoryId ) {
        categoryId = +categoryId;

        return $.Deferred( function ( dfd ) {

            var isLoaded = form.find( 'select.product-subcategories' )
                .map( function ( index, el ) {
                    if ( +$( this ).data( 'category' ) === categoryId ) {
                        return el;
                    }
                }),
                markup = [ ];

            if ( isLoaded.length ) {
                console.log( 'SubCategory loaded from DOM' );
                dfd.resolve( isLoaded );
            } else {
                markup.push( '<select data-category="' + categoryId +  '" class="product-subcategories">' );

                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: '/',
                    data: { categoryId: categoryId }    
                });

                request.done( function ( result ) {
                    //simulate success :X
                    result = {"status":1,"data":[{"name":"Sub-Category I","id":1},{"name":"Sub-Category II","id":2},{"name":"Sub-Category III","id":3}]};

                    var status = result.status,
                        data = result.data,
                        i = 0,
                        il = data.length,
                        current;

                    console.log( 'SubCategory loaded with Ajax' );

                    if ( status !== 1 || !data ) {
                        dfd.reject();
                        return;
                    }

                    for ( current = data[ i ]; i < il; i++ ) {
                        markup.push( '<option value="' + current.id + '">' );
                        markup.push( current.name + '</option>' );  
                    }

                    markup.push( '</select>' );

                    dfd.resolve( $( markup.join( '' ) ).hide().appendTo( form ) );
                });
            }

        }).promise();
    };

    var form = $( '#new-product-form' )
        .on( 'change', 'select.product-categories', function ( e ) {
            getSubCategories( $( this ).val() )
                .done( function( el ) {
                    form.find( 'select.product-subcategories' )
                        .not( el )
                            .hide()

                    el.show();
                });
        });
});
```

As a side note, just wanted to bring up that you don't have any handling of problems if the ajax request fails. You would need to `reject` in that case, and make sure you write `fail` methods. Just a heads up.

Comment: Thanks for the Heads up. Just one question, Prepending the variable with a plus transforms it in integer?

Comment: Using the JavaScript unary plus operator attempts to convert a value to a number if it isn't already. It's easy and fast: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#section_6